# ClassNotFoundException using two projects

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have a Java Project (that is built using Maven) that gets built to a JAR. This sits inside an Android Project which gets built to an AAR. This then gets put inside a normal Android app.

The Android App has the following `Gradle` compile statement:

```
compile(name: 'library-debug', ext: 'aar')
```

Unfortunately though, whenever I reference a method inside the `library-debug` project, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory"
```

`slf4j` is being referenced as a Dependency within the `Java` project but it doesn't get included in to the Android library which should then be available in the Android app.

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

To be clear, this is what's happening

1) Java Project -> Gets built to a JAR

2) Android Project -> Includes the Java Project's Jar and gets built to an AAR.

3) Android App -> Includes the Android Project's AAR.

The Android App however doesn't recognise the objects that live in the Java project because they were imported as Maven Dependencies.

Comment: Why the maven tag?

Comment: @Jens Hi. The Java project has is built with using Maven as it's dependency manager.

Comment: But you Show an gradle snipped?

Comment: Yes, Gradle snippet is for the Android project. Android -> Gradle. The Java project -> Maven. I have three projects altogether. Android App, Android Library and Java Library. Android Library has the Java Library JAR. and the Android App has the Android Library.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the `slf4j-api.jar` as dependency to your Project:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
```

or for maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If I do this and re-build, it will complain about other libraries. It complains about them one at a time. The point is - Because the Android project HAS the Java project inside it as a JAR, why doesn't the Android App recognise slf4j and other objects?

Comment: If you build a jar with maven, the third Party jar's will not beincluded. If you want to include the jar's, you have to use the shade plugin

Comment: Check my update to get a clearer picture of what's going on.